# Optimize for loop Java with different object

Tags: java, loops

I want merge to a `for` loop with to different objects like that:

```
            for (BBPostLikeLogs postDetail : bbPostLikeLogs) {
                if (postDetail.getType() == 4) {
                    NewFaqQuestion questions = newFaqQuestionRepository.findByIdQuestion(postDetail.getId_post());
                    if (questions == null) continue;
                    listObjPosts.add(buildObjPostFromQuestions(questions,userAuth));
                }else{
                    BBPost bbPost = bbPostRepository.findById(postDetail.getId_post());
                    if(bbPost == null) continue;
                    listObjPosts.add(buildObjPostFromPosts(bbPost,userAuth));
                }
            }
```

and

```
            for (PostResult postDetail : postNeo4j) {
                if (postDetail.getType() == 4) {
                    NewFaqQuestion questions = newFaqQuestionRepository.findByIdQuestion(postDetail.get_id());
                    if (questions == null) continue;
                    listObjPosts.add(buildObjPostFromQuestions(questions,userAuth));
                }else{
                    BBPost bbPost = bbPostRepository.findById(postDetail.get_id());
                    if(bbPost == null) continue;
                    listObjPosts.add(buildObjPostFromPosts(bbPost,userAuth));
                }
            }
```

To only one (for loop).

Comment: Can you post the code of `PostResult` and `BBPostLikeLogs` please?

Comment: You are iterating through two different iterable objects, you actually need two loops here unless those two iterable are of the same size.

Comment: What you can do is to create an interface 'YourInterfaceName' with getters `get_id()` and  `getType()` and implement this interface in your `PostResult` and `BBPostLikeLogs`. Then you can iterate like for (YourInterfaceName object : bbPostLikeLogs)  { // do whatever }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create an interface with methods `getType()` and `getId()` and iterate in the loop like `for (YourInterface detail : bbPostLikeLogs) { // do whatever }`.

```
public interface YourInterface {
 int getId();
 int getType();
}

// implement this interface in your classes
public class PostResult  implements YourInterface {

 // Your class code here

 @Override
 public int getId() {
  return this.get_id();
 }

 @Override
 public int getType() {
  return this.getType();
 }
}

public class BBPostLikeLogs implements YourInterface {

  // Your class code here

  @Override
  public int getId() {
   return this.getId_post();
  }

  @Override
  public int getType() {
   return this.getType();
  }
}

// and finally the loop

for (YourInterface detail : bbPostLikeLogs) {
  if (detail.getType() == 4) {
   NewFaqQuestion questions = newFaqQuestionRepository.findByIdQuestion(detail.getId());
   if (questions == null) continue;
   listObjPosts.add(buildObjPostFromQuestions(questions,userAuth));
  } else {
   BBPost bbPost = bbPostRepository.findById(detail.getId());
   if(bbPost == null) continue;
   listObjPosts.add(buildObjPostFromPosts(bbPost,userAuth));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi #lub0v, thank for comment. Is there everything in java we need a object? Like when we get data from database, we need create new object?

Comment: @BeoStepens Java is an object-oriented programming language, so yes, you need an object almost always. When you get a data from a database you have to store it somewhere in the memory to make some business logic, right? An object is the most convenient way to do that.